# How to insert a new object inside an existent object with react immutable helpers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I am working on an application on Rails with the front end using the react_rails gem. Working with state I have props coming from the server an object that looks like this:  `{assignments: {assignment1: {another_collection}, {response: {key: value, key1: value1, etc: etc }},{assignment2: {collection {}{}{}}}}` when I create new response object comes back from the server as json I have to update the state please note that the second object there is not a response object created. I am trying the following code to update state.

```
 addResponse(assignment, response) {
    let indexa = this.state.assignments.indexOf(assignment);
    let assignments = React.addons.update(this.state.assignments, {[indexa]: {   response: {$push: [response]}}});
    this.setState({assignments: assignments})
}
```

I get the following error on the console:
"expected target of $push to be an array; got Cliente indica que esta botando aceite por debajo." which is the value of on of the key assignment:  for the Object assignments. On the example object you can see that there is a response object already created and sent by the server. How to solve this one?

Comment: according to your example `response` is an object, so you can't use `$push`, which can only be used on arrays